# How can we iterate and change an array inplace in an object in JSONata?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonata

I have an JSON obect where I have an key **policyList** whose value type is array. Inside **policyList** there is another array under the key named **product**.

Here I want to change the value of **amount** which is inside each object of the array **product**.

I am able to change it but in the end I am getting only the array of **amount** where as I want the whole orignal object which modified amount values.

Please refer to [this link](https://try.jsonata.org/WZHfozVAq) for the data in JSONata Exerciser link where I have the data and the expression I have written.

JSON:

```
{
  "admissionDate": "2023-10-04",
  "claimCaseId": 123,
  "claimCaseStatusDescp": "Waiting",
  "claimTypeDescp": "Hospitalization",
  "dischargeDate": "2023-10-20",
  "hospital": "abc",
  "policyList": [
    {
      "policyNo": "P1",
      "product": [
        {
          "amount": 10243,
          "claimDecision": "7",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Pending",
          "productName": "Auto"
        },
        {
          "amount": 1023,
          "claimDecision": "7",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Pending",
          "productName": "Mob"
        },
        {
          "amount": 100000,
          "claimDecision": "8",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Approved",
          "productName": "PA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "reasonCode": ""
}
```

The expression I have written is:

```
$map($.policyList.product.amount, function($amount) {
    $formatNumber($amount,'#,###')
})
```

The output coming is:

```
[
  "10,243",
  "1,023",
  "100,000"
]
```

The expected output is:

```
{
  "admissionDate": "2023-10-04",
  "claimCaseId": 123,
  "claimCaseStatusDescp": "Waiting",
  "claimTypeDescp": "Hospitalization",
  "dischargeDate": "2023-10-20",
  "hospital": "abc",
  "policyList": [
    {
      "policyNo": "P1",
      "product": [
        {
          "amount": "10,243",
          "claimDecision": "7",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Pending",
          "productName": "Auto"
        },
        {
          "amount": "1,023",
          "claimDecision": "7",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Pending",
          "productName": "Mob"
        },
        {
          "amount": "100,000",
          "claimDecision": "8",
          "claimDecisionDescp": "Approved",
          "productName": "PA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "reasonCode": ""
}
```

**NOTE: In the expected output I have shown amount as a string but I am okay with any data type there, given that my operations on the value is present in the output in place**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a nested object in place, you can use the [Transform operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform):

```
$$ ~> |policyList.product|{"amount": $formatNumber(amount,'#,###')}|
```

Check it out live on [Stedi Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJzFU11LwzAU%2FSslHUyhk35MFB%2BEsT0o6Bgo7GHtw10at8DalCQV5zJ%2Fu2kT11aFDV%2FMS5J7zrn33EuyWCDBSo4J8hB5KzgRgrJcX0D5KtD7Ls4dJ0aQZrSGJiBJjG50KPTDaBD4A38YI8%2Bw8AZoNgZB7tOKE4TRd%2BBJgizFhAhcmCxzoJLmq26K521BWpw7JgoqYUPfQWoLB25KBV4DX5GfpkL%2FwFpbtSHAEh%2BQgm0o3j5QIStsUQUdZ2e2Bp8yo5wFVmhBztISt5UdtSFBxsq85gR%2BOIy8Llr3OiGYirqrqshVq8YvpNZQZiRPm8E1fOtrCpkdyaiUuoOGtPdOs%2Fs%2Fbh%2FZ8g9mq3Xc7vXJdkeFNvZK0uN%2BZ6OO3a9jYg71PbHPjRMQLB%2Bz1Eor4V5%2FsV7P%2Bbh1VPMaL2wVtWt32XthPAM5LbMl4Wcm7vVdz3Xd%2Fvle6URMhSpSQ5R46BIln8rKGhI%3D).

Comment: I was not aware of the transform operator. This works! Thanks a lot!